# how to arrange a file with detecting a word

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
Peak Ret. Time: 2.083 Min
Number of Points: 6
187.0   194009.0
188.0   308396.0
189.0   319163.0
190.0   321506.0
191.0   321962.0
192.0   321474.0
Peak Ret. Time: 2.683 Min
Number of Points: 6
187.0   194009.0
188.0   308396.0
189.0   319163.0
190.0   321506.0
191.0   321962.0
192.0   321474.0
Peak Ret. Time: 2.417 Min
Number of Points: 4
187.0   20844.0
188.0   30229.0
189.0   31131.0
190.0   30874.0
Peak Ret. Time: 2.667 Min
Number of Points: 8
187.0   59137.0
188.0   75392.0
189.0   64461.0
190.0   51970.0
191.0   41550.0
192.0   33235.0
193.0   22146.0
194.0   19069.0
```

Here I want to have a data like this

```
Peak Ret. Time: 2.083 Min   2.683 Min   2.417 Min   2.667 Min

187              194009      194009      20844      59137
188              308396      308396      30229      75392
189              319163      319163      31131      64461
190              321506      321506      30874      51970
191              321962     321962        0         41550
192              321474     321474        0         33235
193                0           0          0         22146
194                0           0          0         19069
```

At first, I want to search for the data with longest Number of point (in this case it is 8) then I use its first column to the new data. then I remove all other part from the first column because it is repeated, over and over but with different or equal length. Then I put the second column of the first part (2.083 min) then the second column part of the second etc until the end. At the end I fill the empty spaces with zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We read the data with `readLines`, then get the index of those lines that start with numbers ('i1'), with 'Peak' ('nm1').  Extract the 'Peak' value from 'nm1' with `sub`' as well as extract the Time value for creating the header.

We `split` the 'lines' that start with numbers (`lines[i1]`) with a grouping vector we created with 'i1', read the data with `fread` (from `data.table`).  We change the column names of each of the 'lst' element with 'nm2' then `merge` the elements of the `list` with the first column 'Peak'

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- grep('^\\d+', lines)
nm1 <- grep('^Peak', lines, value=TRUE)
nm2 <- c(unique(sub('\\s+.*', '', nm1)),
     sub('.*:\\s+', '', nm1) )

lst <- lapply(lapply(split(lines[i1],
   cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(i1)!=1))), paste, collapse='\n'), 
       fread, header=FALSE)
lst1 <- lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) 
       setnames(lst[[i]],  c(nm2[1],nm2[-1][i])))
 res <-  Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'Peak', all=TRUE),lst1)
dim(res)
#[1] 427  58
res[1:3, 1:3, with=FALSE]
#   Peak 2.083 Min 2.417 Min
#1:  187    194009     20844
#2:  188    308396     30229
#3:  189    319163     31131
```

#### data

```
path <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3d40de7d2cb6d5ab97e5/raw/2412d824ca31ba7a927d5c46f7b091e69eb6b400/sam.asc"
lines <- readLines(path)
```

Comment: I got an error Error in merge.data.table(..., by = "V1", all = TRUE) : 
  x has some duplicated column name(s): V2.x,V2.y. Please remove or rename the duplicate(s) and try again.

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet  Updated based on the data in the link.

Answer (score 1):

We can create an index of the `Peak` rows and use that to subset the original data frame. We also make a name column from the same index and sub out the extra text. Then create a data frame from the remaining text. Using `read.table` the function will separate the pasted values for us to get it ready for `dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)
ind1 <- grepl("Peak", mydata$V1)
mydata$names <- sub(".*: ", "", mydata$V1[ind1][cumsum(ind1)])
ndf <- read.table(text=do.call(paste, mydata[!(ind1|grepl("Number", mydata$V1)),c("V1", "names")]))
dcast(ndf, V1~paste(V3,V4), value.var="V2", fill=0L)
#    V1 2.083 Min 2.417 Min 2.667 Min 2.683 Min
# 1 187    194009     20844     59137    194009
# 2 188    308396     30229     75392    308396
# 3 189    319163     31131     64461    319163
# 4 190    321506     30874     51970    321506
# 5 191    321962         0     41550    321962
# 6 192    321474         0     33235    321474
# 7 193         0         0     22146         0
# 8 194         0         0     19069         0
```

Comment: I got two errors Error in paste(mydata[!(ind1 | grepl("Number", mydata$V1)), "V1"], labels) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'   and Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'ndf' not found

Comment: I liked your answer and I thank you but it did not work for me