# how to rearrange a data based on repeated value

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
Peak Ret. Time: 2.083 Min
Number of Points: 6
187.0   194009.0
188.0   308396.0
189.0   319163.0
190.0   321506.0
191.0   321962.0
192.0   321474.0
Peak Ret. Time: 2.683 Min
Number of Points: 6
187.0   194009.0
188.0   308396.0
189.0   319163.0
190.0   321506.0
191.0   321962.0
192.0   321474.0
Peak Ret. Time: 2.667 Min
Number of Points: 6
187.0   59137.0
188.0   75392.0
189.0   64461.0
190.0   51970.0
191.0   41550.0
192.0   33235.0
193.0   22146.0
194.0   19069.0
```

what I would like to have as output is like below

```
      187point  188point    189point    190point    191point    192point
2.083   194009  308396      319163      321506      321962      321474
2.683   194009  308396      319163      321506      321962      321474
2.667   59137   75392       64461       51970       41550       33235
```

At end one plot of column one versus all other columns in one plot is also appreciated. An example of the read data is pasted here.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? (`dput`)

Comment: @Sotos I gave my real data in the link I posted

Comment: Is your "real data" just a file with text in it, in the same format as you put in the question? Is "Number of points" supposed to correspond to the number of following points? Because the last block has more than six.

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet it is not a matter of giving data but it is a matter of let us understand what kind of R structures contains the data (a list of lists, a matrix a data frame etc.)

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet Please dput(dataframe) and give us the output.

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet not everyone has access to personal storage networks.

Comment: @Sotos the problem is that when I my original data in R, it appears to be in two columns and when I have the example loaded. it is all in one column which is not representative . this is the main reason I gave my data

Comment: @MaxPD I explained the problem above

Comment: It means you are not reading the data correctly if there are two columns and you are getting 1. Take a step back and fix that problem first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a transpose of `res` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488772/how-to-arrange-a-file-with-detecting-a-word/35489020#35489020)

```
 res1 <- t(res)
 res2 <- res1[-1,]
 colnames(res2) <- as.character(res1[1,])
 res2[1:3,1:3]
 #           187    188    189
 #2.083 Min 194009 308396 319163
 #2.417 Min  20844  30229  31131
 #2.667 Min  59137  75392  64461
```

Comment: thanks, you rock, I liked your answer, I accepte it and I thank you, the reason you are 140k is not based on chance , is based on high level of understanding and knowing R way much much better than many who ask such a dummy questions ! I thank you again

Comment: is it possible to tell me how to remove the "min" from the first column and make that column as value instead character ?

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet  Based on the expected output showed, I thought it as row names.  So, if you want to extract the value and create as a column `res3 <- cbind(Time=as.numeric(sub('\\s+.*', '', row.names(res2))), res2); row.names(res3) <- NULL`

Answer (score 2):

I would read the file in with `fread` from "data.table", then use `dcast` to reshape the data once a few modifications are made.

The following worked for me with the sample you shared:

```
library("data.table")
x <- fread("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3d40de7d2cb6d5ab97e5/raw/2412d824ca31ba7a927d5c46f7b091e69eb6b400/sam.asc", header = FALSE)
```

Here's the `dcast` step:

```
out <- dcast(x[, c("peak_ret_time", "N") := list(V2[1], sequence(.N)), 
               by = cumsum(grepl("Peak", V1))][N > 2], 
             peak_ret_time ~ V1, value.var = "V2")
```

You can also do the following if you want to convert the values to numeric:

```
out[, (names(out)) := lapply(.SD, type.convert)]
```

---

Compare `dim(out)` with the expected values. The number of columns is greater than the number of values because the first column is the "peak_ret_time".

```
dim(out)
# [1]  57 428

sum(grepl("Peak", x$V1))
# [1] 57

unique(x$V2[grepl("Number", x$V1)])
# [1] "427"

out[1:6, 1:6, with = FALSE]
##    peak_ret_time    187.0    188.0    189.0    190.0    191.0
## 1:    16.217 Min  30718.0  38885.0  32012.0  24276.0  18139.0
## 2:    17.433 Min  52646.0  69443.0  59216.0  47639.0  37672.0
## 3:    18.617 Min  58199.0  84889.0  71242.0  55595.0  42094.0
## 4:    19.183 Min  66975.0  97531.0  82464.0  64679.0  49354.0
## 5:     2.083 Min 194009.0 308396.0 319163.0 321506.0 321962.0
## 6:     2.417 Min  20844.0  30229.0  31131.0  30874.0  30638.0
```

Comment: that is very good ! thanks, however, once i load the data from desktop I get such error at the begging Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , `:=`(c("peak_ret_time", "N"), list(V2[1],  : 
  unused argument (by = cumsum(grepl("Peak", V1))) . I load the data like this sam <- read.delim("path to the data/sam.asc", header=FALSE)

Comment: @koskeshkiramtodahanet, use `fread` to read the data in. Otherwise, you can also convert to a `data.table` (using `setDT(sam)`) but make sure that the columns are named "V1" and "V2".

Comment: I liked your answer and I learned from it. I really appreciate your commands and your help and I understand the value of your work! I can say THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 1):

I might have over-complicated this. But here's my try at this, which might account for occasions when number of points can be not constant.

```
require(reshape2)
x <- readLines("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/3d40de7d2cb6d5ab97e5/raw/2412d824ca31ba7a927d5c46f7b091e69eb6b400/sam.asc")
x <- read.table(text = x, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors=F)
temp <- unlist(apply(cbind(x[grep("^Peak", x$V1),2], x[grep("^Number", x$V1),2]), 1, 
               function(x) list(rep(x[1], times = as.numeric(x[2])))))
x <- x[grep("^Peak|^Number", x$V1, invert=T),]
x <- cbind(temp, x) 
x <- dcast(x, temp ~ V1, value.var="V2")
```

Regardless, had fun practicing cracking weird data structures.

Comment: You rock, thank you so much. I liked your answer because I learned from it. I hope you like the answers of Akrun and Ananda Mahto. Both gave amazing answers. The only things I accepted Arkun because it was very simple but I love you guys because I learned from you. Thank you